# Java strange features of the String class

Tags: java

In Java, the word "String" is not a keyword. That is, we can write:

```
String String = "";
```

without the compiling error.

Also, java.lang.String class can not be used as a second parameter of the "instanceof" operator.

Why? What's so special about the String class for the Java compiler and why it isn`t a keyword?

Comment: It's not a keyword because it's not a base type.  You wouldn't want every standard library class to be a reserved keyword, or else you couldn't call things `Socket` or `File`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, String is a Class name, not a keyword. So you are free to use it as a variable name, although it's not recommended.

Second, I don't think your statement on "*java.lang.String class can not be used as a second parameter of the "instanceof" operator*" is correct.

I have created a test program named `T2.java`, it compiles and runs as expected:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class T2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String String = "abc";
      outputAll((String instanceof java.lang.String), String);
    }

    public static void outputAll(Object... args) {
      System.out.println();
      for (Object o: args) {
        System.out.println(o);
      }
    }

    public static void output(String msg, Object... args) {
      System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `String` class can be used as the class parameter of the `instanceof` operator. My guess is that if you have:

```
String String = ""
if(String instanceof String)
  // ...
```

The compiler sees `String` on the right hand side of `instanceof` and thinks it isn't a class name since you defined a variable named `String` in that scope.

Try renaming your variable & see what happens.

Edit: After seeing alexvetter's answer, I realize I (in the above) am wrong. `String instanceof String` works fine for me.

`String` isn't a keyword because it's simply a normal class. Keywords are generally reserved for things that control the language & that - if used as variables - would confuse meaning & make for difficulty in parsing. You can use a `String` in all of the same ways you can use any other object in Java.

Comment: No, your sample code compiles and runs good. My JDK version is `1.6.0_24`

Comment: Yes, thus my "Edit: ..." I realized my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can use `String` as second parameter of `instanceof`. There is nothing special about the `String` class. The second parameter of `instanceof` wants a `Class` and the first parameter wants an expression (a variable is a valid expression).

This works for me (tried it):

```
String String = "";
if(String instanceof String) {
     System.out.println("hallo");
}
```

Comment: Tried it out - and "instanceof" works with String type. Sorry, that was my fault.